# Larave: Auth::guest() not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

**So i was using laravel's guard for auth**
This was working properly the log in and the log out of the user

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
   'username' => $request->username, 
   'password' => $request->password])) 
 {
            return redirect('/admin-home');
 }

if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/login-admin');
}
```

However, this one doesnt work, it still go to choose_login even the user is logged in

```
function chooseLogin() {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return view('auth.choose_login');
    }
    else {
        return back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are checking the correct guard:

```
function chooseLogin() {
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->guest()) {
        return view('auth.choose_login');
    }
    else {
        return back();
    }
}
```